# How to fix "same prop getting passed to children" in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

So I am preety new to react js. I am creating a blog app. I am storing blog data in the state and passing it to the children component. In the following piece of the code, I have Feeds component where I am fetching data from the json and storing it in the state. I a passing the data to children component Feed through props.
Now I have an article component which is the child of the Feed which opens as a modal. 
The problem however is no matter which Feed I click on, it opens the same article (whichever was last enetered).

Feeds.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Feed from "./Feed";

class Feeds extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      feeds: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/items")
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, feeds: data });
      console.log("data " + data);
     })
      .catch(err => console.log("Error !! : " + err));
  }

  render() {
    let { isLoaded, feeds } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h4> Loading ..</h4>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Feed feedData={feeds} key={feeds.id} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
// const style for class Feed

export default Feeds;
```

Feed.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Article from "../component/Article";

class Feed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Id: " );
    console.log(this.props.feedData, "feedData");
    let modalClose = () => this.setState({ showModal: false });
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <ul className="list-group" key={this.props.feedData.id}>
          {this.props.feedData.map(feed => (
            <li
              className="list-group-item"
              style={styles.container}
              key={feed.id}
            >
              <div className="container">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-default"
                    onClick={() => this.showModal()}
                  >
                    <h3 style={styles.heading}>{feed.title} </h3>
                  </button>
                  <p>by - {feed.author}</p>
                  <p>{feed.subTitle}</p>
                  <div>
                    <span className="badge">Posted {feed.date}</span>
                    <div className="pull-right">
                      <button className="btn btn-primary">Upvote</button>{" "}
                      <button className="btn btn-info">Comment</button>{" "}
                      <button className="btn btn-danger">Report</button>{" "}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />

                  <Article
                    key={feed.id}
                    show={this.state.showModal}
                    onHide={modalClose}
                    data={feed}
                  />
                </div>
                <hr />
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Article.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

class Article extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    console.log("This is working. Visibility: " + this.props.visible);
    console.log("This is the id of the feed: " + this.props.key);
    return (
      <div className="article">
        <Modal
          {...this.props}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              {this.props.data.title}
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4> {this.props.data.subTitle} </h4>
            <p>{this.props.data.content}</p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Article;
```

I have setup the title in Feed.jsx as a button to open modal.
Each Feed is opening the same article and on console. it shows that the props id is undefined..

console:

```
Id: Feed.jsx:22
(2) […]
​
0: Object { _id: "5cf24b53431f5f089496354b", author: "Arjun", title: "Liberalism and Loyality", … }
​
1: Object { _id: "5cf7a4b26332500efc0d1919", author: "Kapil Goel", title: "Made my first website", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
 feedData Feed.jsx:23
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Feed`.for more information.
    in li (at Feed.jsx:29)
    in Feed (at Feeds.jsx:38)
    in div (at Feeds.jsx:37)
    in Feeds (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:14)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:9) index.js:1375
    e index.js:1375
    React 5
    render Feed.jsx:26
    React 13
    componentDidMount Feeds.jsx:19
This is working. Visibility: undefined Article.jsx:10
This is the id of the feed: undefined Article.jsx:11
This is working. Visibility: undefined Article.jsx:10
This is the id of the feed: undefined Article.jsx:11
feedData is Array:  false Feeds.jsx:20
GEThttp://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/432/v3s4dxpn/websocket
```

Comment: In the Feeds component when you render <Feed feedData={feeds} key={feeds.id} />

is there a reason why you handle feeds, which should be an array, as an object?

Comment: I want it to be passed as an array.. Is this an incorrect way ?

Answer (score 3):

We can't use the `key` keyword as a custom prop in react component because it is pre-reserved in react.

Mostly, `key` keyword is used in iteration to identify the element in the loop or provide a unique identity to element in the loop.

You can use `feedId` as a prop,

```
<Article
  // key={feed.id}
  feedId={feed.id} // you can use feedId instead of key
  show={this.state.showModal}
  onHide={modalClose}
  data={feed}
/>
```

Also in `Article.jsx`, You are using `this.props.visible` to console but you have not passed it as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    axios
  .get("http://localhost:5000/api/items")
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true, feeds: data });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("Error !! : " + err));
```

If you could console.log the data before you put it in setState. It is important to know whether data is in array format or not. 
You either cannot access feeds.id for the "key" prop for the Feed component in Feeds
or you might have a bigger problem because you serve the Feed component an Object even tho it expects an array

Comment: You sure? try console.log("feedData is Array: ", Array.isArray(this.props.feedData))
in the Feed component

Comment: you might want to console.log(feeds.id) in Feeds component. I guess its undefined.

Comment: I am getting `feedData is Array:  false`

Comment: can you console.log(this.props.feedData, "feedData") in the render of the Feed component?

you can use .map function which you use in Feed only for Arrays by default

Comment: I have code the question. Check out the consol.log.

Comment: <prototype>: Array []
 feedData Feed.jsx:23
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

So it seems that your feedData is not an Array in Feeds but an Array in Feed... lol

Comment: Do you have something like PropTypes.. Feed.defaultProps = { some default props }

Comment: The feed data is getting passed to Feed.jsx as an array. However I think the error is in the part where I have called the <Article> in map function. I think It is traversing through all the feeds (i;e passing all the feeds as a prop one by one) and displaying the last one. I may be wrong though